# Extra ip rule table breaking my connectivity with container

Tags: networking, linux-networking

I have host with one interface that has the ip `10.0.10.5/28`. The host has one container with the interface cali02ad7e68ce1 and ip `10.42.1.2/26`. This is the main routing table of the host:

```
$> ip r list table main
default via 10.0.10.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.0.10.0/28 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.10.5 metric 100 
10.42.1.2 dev cali02ad7e68ce1 scope link
```

This is the list of ip rules:

```
$> ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
30400:  from 10.0.10.5 lookup 30400
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

And this is the routing table 30400:

```
$> ip r list table 30400
default via 10.0.10.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 10 
10.0.10.1 dev eth0 proto static scope link metric 10
```

When I try to ping the container `ping 10.42.1.2`, I receive no packets. However, if I tcpdump on the container's interface, I can see both echo request and echo reply.

```
$> sudo tcpdump -eni cali02ad7e68ce1
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on cali02ad7e68ce1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:57:24.589384 ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee > 4e:b1:cd:f0:62:82, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.0.10.5 > 10.42.1.2: ICMP echo request, id 34667, seq 1, length 64
15:57:24.589405 4e:b1:cd:f0:62:82 > ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.42.1.2 > 10.0.10.5: ICMP echo reply, id 34667, seq 1, length 64
15:57:25.637186 ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee > 4e:b1:cd:f0:62:82, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.0.10.5 > 10.42.1.2: ICMP echo request, id 34667, seq 2, length 64
15:57:25.637216 4e:b1:cd:f0:62:82 > ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.42.1.2 > 10.0.10.5: ICMP echo reply, id 34667, seq 2, length 64
```

As soon as I delete the rule `30400`, ping works. I am confused because I don't understand how that rule makes the echo reply to never reach the ping process. AFAIK, that rule should only apply when `10.0.10.5` is source ip. Any help or guess will be appreciated!

### UPDATE

Adding bridge info as requested in the comments:

```
$> ip -br link; ip -br address`
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> 
eth0             UP             06:e4:85:e5:1b:94 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
cali02ad7e68ce1@if3 UP             ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
eth0             UP             10.0.10.5/28 
cali02ad7e68ce1@if3 UP             fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 

$> ip -br link show type bridge
$> ip -br link show type bridge_slave
$>
```

### UPDATE 2

```
$> ping 10.42.1.2 &
[1] 1645713
$> PING 10.42.1.2 (10.42.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.

$> sudo nstat -az TcpExtIPReversePathFilter
#kernel
TcpExtIPReversePathFilter       0                  0.0
$> sudo nstat -az TcpExtIPReversePathFilter
#kernel
TcpExtIPReversePathFilter       0                  0.0
$> ip route get 10.0.10.5 from 10.42.1.2 iif cali02ad7e68ce1
local 10.0.10.5 from 10.42.1.2 dev lo table local 
    cache <local> iif cali02ad7e68ce1
```

Comment: Thanks for the meta-comment. I don't know why I did not choose it as a correct answer. Now it is done :)

Comment: Adding the requested output in the main description for readability. No bridge apparently

Comment: So from the name it's most certainly set up by [calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/) but as I don't know this, I can't understand the reason the interface cali02ad7e68ce1 is left without address and not as bridge port. If it was using for example 10.42.1.1 (and the container behind had relevant configuration) I would understand better. The only address left to be selected is 10.0.10.5 leading to @Anton Danilov's observation

Comment: `cali02ad7e68ce1` is a veth interface. The other end of the interface is in a namespace with the IP `10.42.1.2`

Comment: I am fully aware of this. But this interface *should* have an IP address but doesn't. That's not usually how routing is done. It's certainly handled by Calico / K8s but no context is available to try and figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the reverse path checking issue. Please check the counter with `nstat -az TcpExtIPReversePathFilter`. If the counter is being incremented, then check the route to source of these packets with command

```
ip route get 10.0.10.5 from 10.42.1.2 iif cali02ad7e68ce1
```

Likely you will get the error.

The reverse path filter checks the route to the source of incoming packets and can drop the packets received on unexpected interface. The action depends on the value of sysctl variable `net.ipv4.conf.<iface>.rp_filter`.

The solutions:

- Disable the rp_filter or set it into the loose mode (value `2` of `net.ipv4.conf.<iface>.rp_filter`) - see the sysctl documentation.
- Set the additional route to container in the `30400` routing table.

**Update:**

The output of commands shows the reverse path filter doesn't drop any packets (SNMP counter is zero, route is valid).  So the cause of issue is in something other. Check the firewall rules with `iptables-save -c` command. It shows the full rule set with hit counters. May be some rule blocks the reply packets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Adding the output from the suggested commands in the main description for readability purposes. I don't get an error so I guess it must be something else :(

Comment: I've updated the answer. Check the firewall rules.